# GroupBy in scala

Tags: scala

I have

```
val a = List((1,2), (1,3), (3,4), (3,5), (4,5))
```

I am using `A.groupBy(_._1)` which is groupBy with the first element. But, it gives me output as

```
Map(1 -> List((1,2) , (1,3)) , 3 -> List((3,4), (3,5)), 4 -> List((4,5)))
```

But, I want answer as

```
Map(1 -> List(2, 3), 3 -> List(4,5) , 4 -> List(5))
```

So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make life easy with pattern match and `Map#withDefaultValue`:

```
scala> a.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, List[Int]].withDefaultValue(Nil)){ 
         case(r, (x, y)) => r.updated(x, r(x):+y) 
       }
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = 
      Map(1 -> List(2, 3), 3 -> List(4, 5), 4 -> List(5))
```

There are two points:

1. `Map#withDefaultValue` will get a map with a given default value, then you don't need to check if the map contains a key.
2. When somewhere in scala expected a function value `(x1,x2,..,xn) => y`, you can always use a pattern matching `case(x1,x2,..,xn) => y` here, the compiler will translate it to a function auto. Look into [8.5 Pattern Matching Anonymous Functions](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html) for more information.

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Thanks @Eastsun. Can you please explain me this in detail?

Answer (score 12):

You can do that by following up with `mapValues` (and a `map` over each value to extract the second element):

```
scala> a.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(4 -> List(5), 1 -> List(2, 3), 3 -> List(4, 5))
```

Comment: Note that `mapValues` is lazy, so `_.map(_._2)` will be called each time you access a value from the resulting `Map`. Use `map{case (k, v) => k -> v.map(_._2)}` if you want to avoid this.

Comment: .map is also lazy, how is map{case (k, v) => k -> v.map(_._2)} is not?

Answer (score 4):

As from `Scala 2.13` it would be possible to use [`groupMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupMap[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,CC[B]])
so you'd be able to write just:

```
// val list = List((1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5))
list.groupMap(_._1)(_._2)
// Map(1 -> List(2, 3), 3 -> List(4, 5), 4 -> List(5))
```

Answer (score 3):

As a variant:

```
a.foldLeft(Map[Int, List[Int]]()) {case (acc, (a,b)) => acc + (a -> (b::acc.getOrElse(a,List())))}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with a `foldLeft` to have only one iteration.

```
a.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, List[Int]])((map, t) => 
  if(map.contains(t._1)) map + (t._1 -> (t._2 :: map(t._1))) 
  else map + (t._1 -> List(t._2)))

scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(1 -> List(3, 2), 3 ->
       List(5, 4), 4 -> List(5))
```

If the order of the elements in the lists matters you need to include a `reverse`.

```
a.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, List[Int]])((map, t) => 
  if(map.contains(t._1)) (map + (t._1 -> (t._2 :: map(t._1)).reverse)) 
  else map + (t._1 -> List(t._2)))

scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(1 -> List(2, 3), 3 ->
       List(4, 5), 4 -> List(5))
```