# Scala grouping of Sequence of <Key, Value(Key)> to Map of <Key, Seq(Value)>

Tags: scala, scala-collections

What is the most "Scala way" to convert `Seq[(UUID, DataRecord)]` to `Map[UUID, Seq[DataRecord]]`?

Got a `Data` object of:
`case class DataRecord(id: UUID)`

And a collection of Tuples of them `val data: Seq[(UUID, DataRecord)]` where each Tuple _.1 is corresponding to the `id` in `Data`.

How to group them into `Map[UUID, Seq[DataRecord]]`?

Comment: `mySeq.groupBy(_._1)`

Comment: Thanks but the result would be `Map[UUID, Seq[(UUID, DataRecord)]]`

Comment: Yes, that's what the `mapValues` part is for. The highest voted [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33472589/2707792) is the better solution.

Comment: Thanks, that helped!

Comment: Be aware that `mapValues` is lazy so you may want to use `map` rather than `mapValues` if you are going to access the `Map` multiple times.